# Port and IP address - what does bind mean?

Tags: tcp, port

1. I read on Ports WIKI page that "*Ports are logical constructs which identifies a service or process*", what service or process means here? It means protocol like HTTP, FTP etc. or software applications which are configured to listen on that port?
2. When it is said that application is listening on so and so... then does it listen for request to an IP address or a port, or listens on a combination of port and IP address? Application listen for a specific IP address and one or more ports are bound to it OR it listens for a combination of IP and port?

   - For example, I can have application configured for 7001 for HTTP requests and 7002 for HTTPS requests. So, would be listening on 7001 or what?

Answer (score 1):

1. It means the instance of an application started in the background (service) or, typically, by a user (process) that is configured to listen on a port. The protocol is defined entirely in the application and is only bound to the port by convention. This means the client system must connect to a port that is compatible with the protocol the client intends to use.
2. The application binds to both an address and a port. If it specifies the '0.0.0.0' (IPv4, or '::' for IPv6) address, the application is bound to all network adapters. If it specifies the local address of an adapter, then only connections received on the specific adapter will be accepted. An application must explicitly bind and listen on each port (and possibly address) on which it wishes to be reachable.

   - The application can listen and accept connections on multiple ports simultaneously. Your choice of protocol is by convention or configuration. If the client uses the incorrect protocol, expect your service/process to report an error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Applications/services such as a HTTP web server or an FTP server are assigned a port to use/listen on, usually in the config of the application. and they often use a standard port. HTTP for example usually uses port 80.
2. If an app/service is listening it listens to a port and has no relation to a specific IP address. This is because the IP address it is listening on is the IP address of the computer that the app/service it is running on.

Comment: Technically, computers don't have IP addresses.  Network interfaces have one or more IP addresses.  On the Mac OS X system, the manual for `accept(2)` (`man 2 accept`) indicates that in order to receive network traffic, `bind` must have been called on the socket.  `bind` requires specifying an address so that the network layer knows from which interface(s) to forward network traffic.  (Some?) implementations accept an address of `0.0.0.0` (`::` for IPv6) indicating that the socket will receive network traffic from all network interfaces on the computer.